# Pull Shortcode from current post custom field and execute in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I trying to pull a shortcode from a custom field in Wordpress and execute it via either PHP or Javascript. It seem as I am very much unable to do so, maybe it makes sense considering the fact I don't know either of the languages :/

To be specific - the custom field is named eg-EventKarta and should render the string from the current post (the post is rendered through this template, so hopefully it works) into a shortcode wrapper inside Oxygen Builder, it seems my options are as mentioned earlier PHP or Javascript.

Is there anyone out there who could shed some light on this? It would make my life a lot easier!

Comment: Sorry I am very lost by your description. Can you maybe post some code you have already tried to shed more light. Are you writing a PHP function to do this?

Comment: Hi James! Thanks for reaching out! I'll try and be less confusing :): in most cases I've been able to add text to meta boxes or custom fields. The builder lets me insert this information dynamically from the handle of the custom field in a wp post, for instance "event-title" or simular. This way my client can enter information in a form - that populates the template generated from the post. However: I can do this with text and images, but I am not able to enter a shortcode (in this case I need to present a map). What I have left is to replicate the [shortcode] via PHP or Javascript code.

Comment: So I have a custom field / meta field with the handle: eg-Event-Karta  this contains a shortcode from the current post - for example: [hmapsprem id=2] . What I think I need to do is to have the shortcode inserted either via PHP or Javascript. I am kind of lost in how to do it though. The output should render [hmapsprem id=2] or whatever is entered in this field of the current post.